# Arguments not being passed to a function within a function

Tags: r

I am having trouble passing arguments to a function within a function. The values of the arguments are not being passed instead "n" and "x[i]" are.

```
A <- function(n){

  x=rep(0:n)
  for(i in x){
    x[i]=cGCD(n,x[i])
  }
  return (sum(x)/(n+1))

}

cGCD <- function(n,m){

  if((m==n) || (m==0)){
    return (1)
  }else{
    r = n %% m
    return (1 + cGCD(m,r))
  }
}
```

My error:

```
A(10)
    Error in if ((m == n) || (m == 0)) { : 
      missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not that the values are not being passed properly.  You can check that by adding some `print` statements:

```
A <- function(n){

  x=rep(0:n)
  for(i in x){
    x[i]=cGCD(n,x[i])
  }
  return (sum(x)/(n+1))

}

cGCD <- function(n,m){
  print(n)  # Added for debugging
  print(m)  # Added for debugging
  if((m==n) || (m==0)){
    return (1)
  }else{
    r = n %% m
    return (1 + cGCD(m,r))
  }
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
A(10)
[1] 10
integer(0)
Error in if ((m == n) || (m == 0)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

No, there are two problems at work here:

1. The `for (... in ...)` construct gives you the value of the entry in the list, not an index.
2. Array indices in R begin at 1 rather than 0.

Fixing these:

```
A <- function(n){

  x=rep(0:n)
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {  # i is now an index from 1 to 10, rather than the values of x, which are all zeros.
    x[i]=cGCD(n,x[i])
  }
  return (sum(x)/(n+1))

}

cGCD <- function(n,m){

  if((m==n) || (m==0)){
    return (1)
  }else{
    r = n %% m
    return (1 + cGCD(m,r))
  }
}
```

And the output is as you might expect:

```
A(10)
[1] 2.545455
```